# Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx \ge \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \cdot \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous and increase monotonically on $[0,1]$, then
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx \ge \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \cdot \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx \quad ?
$$
The integral is understood in the Riemannian sense, if that is important.

I know that I should show the progress, but I don't have any ideas on how to prove this.

Update: This is a problem from one problem book from the section on definite integrals, so double integrals are not allowed. They have not yet been considered at this point.

Comment: $f(x) = x - 0.5$ makes the right hand side always $0$.

Comment: Apply $$\iint [f(x)-f(y)][g(x)-g(y)]\,dx\,dy\ge 0$$

Comment: Just for the reference: This is called the [Harris inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality#A_special_case:_the_Harris_inequality) and the proof above is the standard one.